# existance of loop with finitely many point of intersection

Tags: manifolds, homotopy-theory, loop-spaces

**for every loop on compact orientable surface exists freely homotopic loop with finitely many points of intersection.**

I see that it have to be true, but I can't prove it. I know Thom's theorem, Sard's theorem.
Could anybody help me?

Comment: Do you know about Riemannian metrics and geodesics? If you do, then you can easily solve this problem.

Comment: @studios unfortunately, I do not know. Could you know a proof which doesn't use Riemannian metrics?

Comment: You need to know something to solve such problems. Do you know Sard's theorem?

Comment: @studiosus Yes, I know it.